# Is there a way to lock head rotation? 1.14.4

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was doing some stuff in my single player world and I wanted my head to always look down, but not making it choppy.

You could do `execute as @p at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~ 90` in a repeating command block, but that makes it very choppy and hard to look at.

Does anyone know a command that could do the same effect but not be choppy?

Comment: This behaviour is reported as a bug at least: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-154621 In general, there are 133 open reports with "teleport" in the title: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-2157?jql=project%20%3D%20MC%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened%2C%20Postponed)%20AND%20summary%20~%20teleport%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20ASC So this might be impossible to do. :D

Comment: noo :( hope they'll fix that in later updates

Answer (score 1):

You could use a command that could move the players head down by a certain value each time. This would mean that instead of locking down, it will smoothly go down at a fast rate. The problem with this is that it will be easier for them to just move their head more, as the process will be slower.

Other than that there is no way to prevent people moving their heads without using some plugins or mods. Hope this was helpful somewhat, sorry about that.